# lwjgl, rotating only one object on screen?

Tags: java, api, lwjgl

So I am trying to only rotate one object, I have read other posts about how to do so but all of them just say something like this:
1. call `glLoadIdentity();`
2. draw shape
3. rotate

I have tried what they tell me to do but it doesn't seem to work for me?

```
if (time != faces.size() - 1 && faces.size() != 1){
            if (faces.get(time+1).needsIdentity){
                GL11.glLoadIdentity();
                System.out.println("The not last identity was set!");
            }
            System.out.println("got identity");
        }else{
            if (faces.get(faces.size() - 1).needsIdentity){
                GL11.glLoadIdentity();
                System.out.println("identity set!");
            }
            System.out.println("got last identity");
        }


        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glColor3f(f.clr.red, f.clr.green, f.clr.blue);
        GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x - f.x, f.loc.y +  f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
        GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x + f.x, f.loc.y + f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
        GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x + f.x, f.loc.y - f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
        GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x - f.x, f.loc.y - f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
        GL11.glEnd();
        finished();
    }

public void finished(){
    GL11.glRotatef(rs.rotx, 1F, 0F, 0F);
    GL11.glRotatef(rs.roty, 0F, 1F, 0F);
    GL11.glRotatef(rs.rotz, 0F, 0F, 1F);
    System.out.println("rotated");
}
```

This is my code.
in the array called `faces` are 4 quads 3 of them have `needsIdentity` false and one of them have it true, also the one I'm trying to rotate.
I have put in the print lines to check if it gets the identity, which it does.
Also to `times` 1 gets added every round.

Can you explane where exactly i have to call the `glLoadIdentity()`?
You might want to know this but it rotates me instead of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rotate only certain parts of a scene (In your case, one object), you can use `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`. This allows you to do transformations (Such as translating, rotating and scaling) and revert after you're done drawing the object you want to transform. Don't bother with `glLoadIdentity()` - That resets all transformations. The reason it probably rotates you is because you probably draw yourself after calling `glRotatef(r, x, y, z)` several times.

```
//Draw some objects here - not rotated

GL11.glPushMatrix(); //Push the matrix onto the stack

//Rotate the object about to be drawn
GL11.glRotatef(rs.rotx, 1F, 0F, 0F);
GL11.glRotatef(rs.roty, 0F, 1F, 0F);
GL11.glRotatef(rs.rotz, 0F, 0F, 1F);

//Draw the object
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glColor3f(f.clr.red, f.clr.green, f.clr.blue);
GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x - f.x, f.loc.y +  f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x + f.x, f.loc.y + f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x + f.x, f.loc.y - f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(f.loc.x - f.x, f.loc.y - f.y, f.loc.z + f.z);
GL11.glEnd();

GL11.glPopMatrix(); //Pop the matrix off of the stack

//Draw some more objects here - not rotated
```